# can i add upload button on dynamic vertical tabs in bootstrap

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to add an upload button to one of my dynamic vertical tab in my bootstrap code. here is the piece of code that i am using :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>TheAnveshaSrivastava</title> 
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" >
        <script  src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script  src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
<style> 
.tabs-right > .nav-tabs,
.tabs-left > .nav-tabs {
  border-bottom: 0;
}

.tab-content > .tab-pane,
.pill-content > .pill-pane {
  display: none;
}

.tab-content > .active,
.pill-content > .active {
  display: block;
}


.tabs-left > .nav-tabs > li,
.tabs-right > .nav-tabs > li {
  float: none;
}

.tabs-left > .nav-tabs > li > a,
.tabs-right > .nav-tabs > li > a {
  min-width: 74px;
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
}

.tabs-left > .nav-tabs {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 19px;
  border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.tabs-left > .nav-tabs > li > a {
  margin-right: -1px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;
     -moz-border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;
          border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;
}

.tabs-left > .nav-tabs > li > a:hover,
.tabs-left > .nav-tabs > li > a:focus {
  border-color: #eeeeee #dddddd #eeeeee #eeeeee;
}

.tabs-left > .nav-tabs .active > a,
.tabs-left > .nav-tabs .active > a:hover,
.tabs-left > .nav-tabs .active > a:focus {
  border-color: #ddd transparent #ddd #ddd;
}   

    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6"><h3>Tabs vertical side</h3>

      <!-- tabs left -->
      <div class="tabbable tabs-left">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
          <li><a href="#a" data-toggle="tab">One</a></li>
          <li class="active"><a href="#b" data-toggle="tab">Two</a></li>
          <li><a href="#c" data-toggle="tab">Twee</a></li>
          <li><a href="#d" data-toggle="tab">Four</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="tab-content">
         <div class="tab-pane active" id="a">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, charetra varius quam sit amet vulputate. 
         Quisque mauris augue, molestie tincidunt condimentum vitae, gravida a libero.</div>
         <div class="tab-pane" id="b">Secondo sed ac orci quis tortor imperdiet venenatis. Duis elementum auctor accumsan. 
         Aliquam in felis sit amet augue.</div>
         <div class="tab-pane" id="c">Thirdamuno, ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis pharetra varius quam sit amet vulputate. 
         Quisque mauris augue, molestie tincidunt condimentum vitae. </div>
         <div class="tab-pane" id="d">Four numero 4 damuno, ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis pharetra varius quam sit amet vulputate. 
         Quisque mauris augue, molestie tincidunt condimentum vitae. </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- /tabs -->

    </div>   
  </div><!-- /row -->
</div>
</body>
```

Could you please help me to achieve the same.Please run the attached piece of code.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried anything ? This should add a button to your tab

```
<label class="btn btn-default btn-file">
Browse <input type="file" hidden>
</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean like this?

```js
$('.tab-pane').each(function(index) {
  const label = '<label class="btn btn-default btn-file">Browse</label>';
  const input = '<input type="file" hidden>';
  //const button = '<button class="btn btn-primary">Upload</button>';
  $(this).append( "<br /><br />", $(label).append(input) );
});
```

```css
.tabs-right > .nav-tabs,
.tabs-left > .nav-tabs {
  border-bottom: 0;
}

.tab-content > .tab-pane,
.pill-content > .pill-pane {
  display: none;
}

.tab-content > .active,
.pill-content > .active {
  display: block;
}


.tabs-left > .nav-tabs > li,
.tabs-right > .nav-tabs > li {
  float: none;
}

.tabs-left > .nav-tabs > li > a,
.tabs-right > .nav-tabs > li > a {
  min-width: 74px;
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
}

.tabs-left > .nav-tabs {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 19px;
  border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.tabs-left > .nav-tabs > li > a {
  margin-right: -1px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;
     -moz-border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;
          border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;
}

.tabs-left > .nav-tabs > li > a:hover,
.tabs-left > .nav-tabs > li > a:focus {
  border-color: #eeeeee #dddddd #eeeeee #eeeeee;
}

.tabs-left > .nav-tabs .active > a,
.tabs-left > .nav-tabs .active > a:hover,
.tabs-left > .nav-tabs .active > a:focus {
  border-color: #ddd transparent #ddd #ddd;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" >
<script  src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script  src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6"><h3>Tabs vertical side</h3>

      <!-- tabs left -->
      <div class="tabbable tabs-left">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
          <li><a href="#a" data-toggle="tab">One</a></li>
          <li class="active"><a href="#b" data-toggle="tab">Two</a></li>
          <li><a href="#c" data-toggle="tab">Twee</a></li>
          <li><a href="#d" data-toggle="tab">Four</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="tab-content">
         <div class="tab-pane active" id="a">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, charetra varius quam sit amet vulputate. 
         Quisque mauris augue, molestie tincidunt condimentum vitae, gravida a libero.</div>
         <div class="tab-pane" id="b">Secondo sed ac orci quis tortor imperdiet venenatis. Duis elementum auctor accumsan. 
         Aliquam in felis sit amet augue.</div>
         <div class="tab-pane" id="c">Thirdamuno, ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis pharetra varius quam sit amet vulputate. 
         Quisque mauris augue, molestie tincidunt condimentum vitae. </div>
         <div class="tab-pane" id="d">Four numero 4 damuno, ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis pharetra varius quam sit amet vulputate. 
         Quisque mauris augue, molestie tincidunt condimentum vitae. </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- /tabs -->

    </div>   
  </div><!-- /row -->
</div>
```